# Racket: Why can't set canvas's background in windows

Tags: racket

This my code:

```
#lang racket

(require racket/gui)

(define-values (screen-width screen-height) (get-display-size))

(define *app-width* 400)

(define *app-height* 125)

(define *vm-frame* (new frame% 
                      [label "Test"]
                      [width *app-width*]
                      [height *app-height*]
                      [x (- (quotient screen-width 2) (quotient *app-width* 2))]
                      [y (- (quotient screen-height 2) (quotient *app-height* 2))]
                      ))

(define frame-canvas%
  (class canvas%
    (super-new)
    (inherit get-dc)

    (define/override (on-paint)
      (let ([my-dc (get-dc)])
        (send my-dc clear)
        (send my-dc set-background "black")))))

(let ([frame-canvas (new frame-canvas% [parent *vm-frame*])])
  (send *vm-frame* show #t))
```

On mac os, this is normal, show a app with a black background.
  But on windows, background is white.
  Why? Racket version is 5.3, it's a 5.3 bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reverse the order of `set-background` and `clear`.

The call to `clear` uses the color of the current background to do the fill.  If somehow your `on-paint` were called at least more than once, then you would observe a black background, since the second time around, the current background color would be black.  I suspect this is what explains the platform-specific difference you observed.